# Slow REST requests using React Native

Tags: rest, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a RN project, we tried using fetch and axios for REST api calls.

the api calls have minimal data on them (change object location with 2 ints as body).
I can see that it takes 5 seconds to get to the server as I log the exact moment it gets to the server.

I tested the server with postman, all the requests finish after 200ms-500ms, going through RNs request using the same network (same wifi) takes 5-10 seconds.

In the iOS simulator (Expo.io) the requests are instant, only when testing on a device (either in development or with a pre-compiled bundle) it takes this long.

How can i fix this? it is not usable for my users :/

We are using RN 0.46.4

Thanks.

Comment: have you try to fetch without JS debugging?

Comment: It happens also when I bundle and run on the device with the pre made bundle, is there a specific way to not use js debugging?

Comment: @RoyiMindel yes close VS and open app from simulator like any other app, and when app is open go to `Command-D` and `STOP REMOTE DEBUGGING`

Comment: We never used remote debugging, so it only says start remote debugging, so i guess this is not the issue?

Comment: I even built as Release, a simple get call that takes 200ms in postman takes 10 secs on the app in ios

Comment: Do you have access to the backend?

Comment: Yes, I might've figured it out, some component was sending lots of other requests (when moving the map on react-native-maps) , once i disabled that the othe request started functioning properly. I am guessing its an issue with how many requests can be called at once on an iphone compared to the simulator, the simulator probably can open more requests at once?